# C++ application does not kill all processes on exit

Tags: c++, qt, process

This is my main.cpp which starts the mainwindow:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TabWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Even with the `a.connect(...)` I do not understand why myApplication.exe still runs after I close the mainwindow. **Any suggestions on how I can fully end all processes after the quit button is clicked?**

**EDIT:** The [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#exec) says this:
We recommend that you connect clean-up code to the aboutToQuit() signal, instead of putting it in your application's main() function. This is because, on some platforms, the QApplication::exec() call may not return.

Comment: do you have any threads that you start up?

Comment: @ratchetfreak  Yes I do. Now that you mentioned, I am using `QtConcurrent`to start a worker thread and this error occurs when I close the application BEFORE the worker thread finishes.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Is there a way to delete all threads before exiting the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment posted by `@ratchetfreak` in my question, I figured out where the problem was.

In my MainWindow, I started **a worker thread which was not terminated** and thus still persisted as a process after the application was closed. In order to fix this, I registered the close event and kept track of the existence of the thread - i.e. basically, ignored the closeEvent until the thread was deleted as well.

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (workerThreadExists) {
        // Gracefully exiting all tasks inside the worker thread
        while (workerThreadExists){
            event->ignore();
        }
        event->accept();

    }
}
```

...and for me `workerThreadExists` is just a `BOOLEAN` that is set to true once the thread is created and then it is set to false when the thread is deleted. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code. And your connect doesn't do anything.

Unless you call [QGuiApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) somewhere, application should exit when the last window is closed. Probably you block event loop somewhere in your window code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TabWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

// Do quit in your TabWindow:
TabWindow::TabWindow()
  : public QWidget(NULL)
{
  connect( ui->myQuitButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), qApp, SLOT( quit() ) );
}
```

Comment: I see your point. But then what can I do to actually kill all processes on exit?

Comment: There's no any infinite loop, because `aboutToQuit` signal can be emitted only once. Calling QApplication::quit() multiple times does not lead to multiple `aboutToQuit` signals.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov that wasnt me man. I fixed it with an upvote. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score -5):

just replace

```
return a.exec();
```

with

```
return 0;
```

That should end all processes which is associated with that program.

Comment: `a.exec()` runs Qt event loop, without it application would be mostly unusable.